# Can Cat5e cable be used for low current 120VAC signals (NOT in production environment - test only!)

Tags: ac, signal, cables, maximum-ratings

We are preparing to deploy an industrial control panel.
Before connecting the panel to the industrial equipment it will control, we want to provide training and allow the staff to practice using the new system in a simulated environment without chance of damaging real equipment.

For this purpose, we have built a simulated operator panel with inputs and outputs duplicating the "real-world" system.

The control panel uses mostly 24VDC for control signals, but also has a few 120VAC control input signals.

The 120VAC IO card in the main panel draws 10mA for each 120VAC input, and there are six 120VAC inputs total.

Would it be safe to use CAT5e cable (10 feet or less) to connect this temporary simulation HMI to the control panel? Is the insulation on CAT5e wires suitable for low-current 120VAC?  I see per Wikipedia it's rated for 128VDC max, but no mention of AC (I am assuming capacitance would make a difference in DC vs AC?)

Again, this is NOT for use in a production environment, but will be used for a few hours to provide simulation training before being disconnected.  The benefit of CAT5e is ease of transport and cost.

Thanks for your input!

Comment: AC means 50 to 60 Hz, so I'm pretty sure you can ignore the capacitance. Anyway, what's the peak voltage of 120 V AC? (120V is the RMS voltage!!) Indeed, it's \$\sqrt2 \cdot120\,\text V\approx 1.4\cdot 120\,\text V = 168\,\text V\$.

Comment: And: if I was an engineer and someone demo'd me his system using essentially network cabling for 120VAC signalling – not a strong selling point.

Comment: plus, I'm pretty sure that typical CAT5 is a nightmare to attach to these terminals that you'd normally attach proper signalling cables for such voltages. It's thin, it's flimsy, it breaks when you try to screw it to anything.

Comment: I forgot about peak AC voltages.  So the insulation is not safe for 168V?  Is that the line of reasoning I need to use?  FYI they are not going to notice/care the type of cable used as long as it works and they don't get a jolt. :)  I just needed to confirm safety.

Comment: This surely just isn't the cable for the job. There are plenty of properly rated multicore cable types available for this kind of application. It's not like you're the first person to ever need a multicore cable. I'm frankly a little surprised that somebody working with industrial applications is considering this.

Comment: @IanBland, "a little surprised" hmm, if that was used surely H+S would be all over all involved...

Comment: For production use... hell no, but for a quick bodge, well I've seen worse. I've seen telecom twisted pair (the big stuff with 2 dozen pairs) used for routing 120V PA lines *along with the phone lines* at a school and that stuffs pretty similar to cat5 in terms of wire gauge and insulation. Would I trust it? No. Will it work, probably. **But**, can't you just cannibalise an extension lead or something instead?

Comment: Thing is, this isn't really a quick bodge. I used to work in theatre electrics so I can bodge like a good'un. I'm quite happy to test circuits by the switch from a distance and see what explodes method. But honestly, all the OP needs is a bit of multicore or even a tripe of singles. Cat 5? Why?

Comment: Thanks everyone for your comments.  Naturally we have standard panel hookup wire (600V MTW) available and I guess we will have to use it, making our own cable bundles.  This little training HMI is a shoestring budget item, and we didn't want to buy a whole roll of multi-core to only use a few feet (not to mention the shipping delays).  So I saw a box of Cat5 sitting there and said "Hmm - can we use it safely?"  You guys have made it quite clear this is a very bad idea, so we'll use the 600V rated cable.  However, can you clarify *why* it's dangerous?  Would the insulation break down at this V?

Answer (score 2):

The issue is primarily one of the insulation rating of the Cat5 cable and secondarily the temperature rise within the cable. I am not aware of any Cat5 cable with a safety rating for use with 120 VAC (this normally implies 600 volt insulation). I would never expose my staff nor any customer to such a safety risk. I would never risk my career based on Wikipedia information either.